# cbioLib vxworks library issue

Tags: vxworks

i have an app running on vxworks os. In the code , there is this read system call which is crashing...

the stack trace is somewhat like below :

```
1fb5ec0 prcb_play_more +258: read (f58e094, 1f40, 3c3a3c3c)
1e1d77c read           +5c : iosRead (f58e094)
1df5928 iosRead        +c8 : 83f800 (3c3a3c3c, f58e094, 1f40)
83f830 dosFsShutdownLogWarningOff+2290: cbioModeGet (3c3a3c3c)
1ddf998 cbioModeGet    +1c : cbioDevVerify (3c3a3c3c)
```

any suggestions on why the above vxworks routine is failing ?

thanks...

Comment: Are u able to identify which device type its crashing, is it ramdisk or flash. Are you using TFFS, which vxworks version?  From stack it seems the target disk is formatted using dosFS, file system. Make a diskcheck and see if there are any errors.

Comment: in the core dump, we can see the following info : data access register       0x3c3a3c3c, the same address which is going in cbioDev call.

Comment: I would advice to enable logging for CBIO (cbioDebug), can help you identify issue better. Also from code read, see who all are using dosFs and identify which disk is causing issue.

Comment: thanks vikash...is there any command we can execute to enable this logging ? where will the output be written ?

Comment: Read corresponding driver code, you will get your answers.